# Merging strings as columns to create a table in bash

Tags: bash, merge

Consider the following strings:

```
$ columnA="A1\nA2\nA3"
$ columnB="B1\nB2\nB3"
$ columnC="C1\nC2\nC3"
```

Using Bash, how can I merge these so that I get another string with the following content:

```
$ echo "$table"
A1;B1;C1\nA2;B2;C2\nA3;B3;C3
```

Comment: I found I can use $'\n' instead of \n to actually insert a newline. A few other ways are also mentioned in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912681/build-a-string-in-bash-with-newlines

Comment: If you have any information to add, then please edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use command `paste`, and process-substitution:

```
table="$(paste -d ';' <(echo -e "$columnA") <(echo -e "$columnB") <(echo -e "$columnC"))"
```

`echo "$table"` will give output as:

```
A1;B1;C1
A2;B2;C2
A3;B3;C3
```

Also don't forget to use `-e` flag with `echo`, otherwise it will not consider `\n`, especially and you will get output:

```
A1\nA2\nA3;B1\nB2\nB3;C1\nC2\nC3
```

Or, use printf:

```
table="$(paste -d ';' <(printf "$columnA") <(printf "$columnB") <(printf "$columnC"))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `datamash`, `xargs`, `tr`:

```
$ table=$(printf '%b\n' "$columnA" "$columnB" "$columnC" | xargs -n3\
    | datamash -t' ' transpose | tr ' ' ';')
$ table="${table//$'\n'/\\n}"
$ echo "$table"
A1;B1;C1\nA2;B2;C2\nA3;B3;C3
```

- `printf '%b\n' ...` print values separated by newlines
- `xargs -n3` combine three values space separated per line
- `datamash -t' ' transpose` transpose the output
- `tr ' ' ';'` replace spaces with semicolons
- `${table//$'\n'/\\n}` replace newlines with literal `\n`